# Python Global File

Tags: python

How can I write to a global file inside of a function?

Example:

```
output_file=open("output_file_name.txt", "w")

def write_to_file:    
    global output_file    
    output_file.write('something')

write_to_file()

output_file.close()
```

The code above is not working. It says "ValueError: I/O operation on closed file" 
Any ideas?

Comment: That code would not give that error.

Comment: Works on Python 2.5, Python 2.7, Python 3.2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

write_to_file is a function,

try

```
def write_to_file():
```

othrwise the code is fine

Answer (score 3):

```
>>> output_file = "output_file"
>>> def write_to_file():
...     global output_file
...     with open(output_file,"w") as f:
...         f.write("I wrote to file")
...     with open(output_file, "r") as f:
...         print f.readlines()
>>> write_to_file()
   ['I wrote to file']
```

It is always better open a file when needed,  rather than opening at the beginning of the script.
Use of `with` ensures all the file handlers are closed before exit.